# Developing FEM/FDTD for Computational Electromagnetics

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, simulations

I am looking to create my own code/model for modeling electromagnetic problems via Finite Element Method and Finite Difference Time Domain method. I have been reading through the literature and textbooks but there is an abundance of information. I am looking to see if anyone has any recommendations on resources for getting started with this endeavor. I know what method I develop is heavily dependent on what I want to do at the end, but I suppose I am looking to stay general for now.

It seems like "Computational Electromagnetics for RF and Microwave Engineering" by Davidson (2011) is a good source and Wikipedia has information. If anyone else has any information, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This related question on FEM in general might help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/621861/bibliography-and-basic-resources-to-get-started-in-the-finite-element-method

Comment: Are you looking for resources on the math behind the methods/models? Or are you looking for how to translate the math into code (so a code-focused set of resources)?

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Honestly, both. But I suppose more so the first one.

Comment: Why did you choose FDTD?

Comment: I am looking to develop a general solution that is capable of looking at static and dynamic problems for problems I am interested. I am picked these methods since I am somewhat familiar with them from using commercial software and I know they are well developed and robust.

Answer (score 1):

I am relarively new in CEM. Here are two books that I have found useful:

- "Computational Methods for Electromagnetics", Peterson, Ray, Mittra, this covers a broad range of algorithms ranging from the Moment Method, Finite Elements and FDTD
- "The Finite Element Method in Electromagnetics", J. Jin, this is more geared towards Finite Element methods, both in Frequency and Time-Domain, but, also covers more advanced topics, such as Domain Decomposition and FETI-DP schemes